# If two classes of structures are elementary, and one can be defined from the other, can the other be defined also?

Tags: model-theory

Suppose we have a certain class $C$ of binary relations $R$ which is an elementary class. Suppose also that we define a class $C'$ of binary relations $S$ in terms of $R$ by a first-order formula. For example, we could define that $S$ is the reflexive closure of $R$, or the symmetric closure of $R$. So that means we can form the definitional extension in the language of two binary relations $\{R,S\}$. So $C'$ is at least a pseudo-elementary class. It is obvious to me that if $R$ can be defined in terms of $S$, then the class $C'$ is in fact an elementary class. I am interested in the converse. That is, if $C'$ is an elementary class, can $R$ be defined in terms of $S$?

Comment: What if $C'$ is the class of empty relations (i.e., $S$ never holds)? Then $C'$ is certainly elementary, but we've lost all the information about $R$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ah, I see. You should post that as an answer. Also, I want to know, am I right in saying "if $R$ can be defined in terms of $S$, then the class $C'$ is in fact an elementary class."?

Comment: I've posted an answer. And yes, you're right that $C'$ must be an elementary class in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C$ be the class of all binary relations (axiomatized by the empty theory), and let $C'$ be the class of empty relations (i.e., $S$ never holds). Then $S$ is definable from $R$ (by $\bot$) and $C'$ is elementary (axiomatized by $\forall x\forall y\,\lnot S(x,y)$), but we can't recover an arbitrary binary relation from the empty relation on the same set.

In fact, in the situation that you can define $R$ from $S$, the operation $(X,R)\mapsto (X,S)$ must be one-to-one. This happens pretty rarely - for example, the reflexive and symmetric closure operations are not one-to-one.

Comment: For the second part, the operation $(X, R) \mapsto (X, S)$ is one-to-one provided $R$ belongs to $C$. So, presumably, the axiomatisation you use for $C'$ is what you get by taking the axioms for $C$ together with the definition of $S$ in terms of $R$ and then replacing $R$ by its definition in terms of $S$ everywhere.